# Getting value by key in hashmap returns null

Tags: java, null, hashmap

I'm trying to store a collection of BasicRectangle objects in a hashmap (which is contained in the class BasicRectangleCollection. The key is an object containing the integer fields x and y.
I'm then using the method "find" to retrieve it, which simply takes the x and y values and turns them into a Key object.  However, when I run "find" then it returns null and I don't understand why this would happen when the object I'm looking for is most definitely present...

Relevant code:

```
HashMap<Key,BasicRectangle> rectangles;

public BasicRectangleCollection(BasicRectangle bRect){
    this.rectangles = new HashMap<>();
    int x = bRect.getX();
    int y = bRect.getY();
    rectangles.put(new Key(x,y), bRect);
}
@Override
public BasicRectangle find(int x, int y) {
    return rectangles.get(new Key(x,y));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BasicRectangle rectangle= new BasicRectangle(0,0,5,5);
    BasicRectangleCollection collection = new BasicRectangleCollection(rectangle);
    BasicRectangle found = collection.find(0,0);
    System.out.println(found);
}
```

Comment: does `Key` and `BasicRectangle` class implement equals and hashcode properly ?

Comment: And yet, you didn't feel that sharing your `Key.equals()` and `Key.hashCode()` implementations with us was important.

Comment: @JigarJoshi `BasicRectangle` does not need those implementations here, only `Key`.

Comment: definite (see OP's comments in answers) duplicate of [Why do I need to override the equals and hashCode methods in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you implemented hashCode and equals for Key and BasicRectangleCollection?

If not, I think Java uses the objects reference in memory as the hashcode which means that unless two objects are the same instance they are not equal and your search will not work as desired.

Comment: ah, erm, no - I didn't *redface*. I assumed that it would inherit a suitable implementation. Thank you for your explanation, I'll go implement that now.... *whistles*

Comment: Sure thing dude! Don't feel bad though, we've all done it ;-). Do you think you could click the green check mark as well so I can get some extra points?

Comment: Sure, I was just waiting for the timer to allow me to :). Thanks again :).

Comment: No problem, have a good one and keep at it! The best way to get better at programming is...well...to program :-) and, usually, people on here are helpful. I'm sure some day you'll be giving back too.

Comment: BasicRectangleCollection doesn't need to implement equals and hashCode. Only Key does.